# Specflow application moving to next step before processing on current step is complete

Tags: c#, .net, process, specflow

I have this step in my `Specflow` applicaiton:

```
[Given(@"Messages are streaming to MF application")]
public void GivenMessagesAreStreamingToMFApplication()
{
    var MessageInjectorOptions = new MessageInjectorOptions();
    _configuration.GetSection("JavaMessageInjector").Bind(MessageInjectorOptions);
    _logger.LogInformation("MessageInjector Command: " + MessageInjectorOptions.MessageInjectorFilename + " " + MessageInjectorOptions.MessageInjectorParameters);
    int applicationStatus = TestHelper.ExecuteApplication(MessageInjectorOptions.MessageInjectorFilename, MessageInjectorOptions.MessageInjectorParameters);
    _logger.LogInformation("MessageInjector Exit Code: " + applicationStatus);
}
```

This is my `TestHelper` class:

```
public class TestHelper
{
    public static int ExecuteApplication(string filename, string arguments="")
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = filename,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            Arguments = arguments
        };
        Process proc;

        if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Message injector failed to run");
        }


        proc.WaitForExit();
        int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        proc.Close();
        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

The Java application generally takes several minutes to execute when run independently but when I run my Specflow applicaiton with `dotnet test --logger:"console;verbosity=detailed;"` the step completes in 0.3s, seemingly without issue. The next step fails as it relies on the previous step having completed successfully.

> Standard Output Messages:
> Given MD messages are streaming to MF application
> test_tool.Steps.IntegrationTestStepDefinitions [0] MessageInjector Command: C:\ProgramData\ME\Java_SymLinks\JDK8_x64\jre\bin\java.exe -jar .\Jar\Injector\Injector-6.0.jar MY.TOPIC
> -> done: IntegrationTestStepDefinitions.GivenMessagesAreStreamingToMFApplication() (0.3s)

I thought `proc.WaitForExit()` would have ensured the application completes before moving on but that has not been the case. How do I ensure the application has finished running before moving on?

Comment: `proc.WaitForExit()` will wait for the process you started directly, but not for any processes it started (or its children started, and so on).  You might want to look into the list of running processes using something like Sysinternals Process Explorer (which displays them in a tree according to creator/child relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my TestHelper to this:

```
public class TestHelper
    {
        public static async Task<ProcessResult> ExecuteShellCommand(string command, string arguments="", int timeout=1000, bool insertWait=false)
        {
            var result = new ProcessResult();

            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var outputCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

                process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // The output stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        outputCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outputBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var errorCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

                process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // The error stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        errorCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                bool isStarted;

                try
                {
                    isStarted = process.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    // Usually it occurs when an executable file is not found or is not executable

                    result.Completed = true;
                    result.ExitCode = -1;
                    result.Output = error.Message;

                    isStarted = false;
                }

                if (isStarted)
                {
                    // Reads the output stream first and then waits because deadlocks are possible
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    if (insertWait)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(150000);
                    }

                    // Creates task to wait for process exit using timeout
                    var waitForExit = WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);

                    // Create task to wait for process exit and closing all output streams
                    var processTask = Task.WhenAll(waitForExit, outputCloseEvent.Task, errorCloseEvent.Task);

                    // Waits process completion and then checks it was not completed by timeout
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), processTask) == processTask && waitForExit.Result)
                    {
                        result.Completed = true;
                        result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;

                        // Adds process output if it was completed with error
                        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                        {
                            result.Output = $"{outputBuilder}{errorBuilder}";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Kill hung process
                            process.Kill();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }


        private static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(Process process, int timeout)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit(timeout));
        }


        public struct ProcessResult
        {
            public bool Completed;
            public int? ExitCode;
            public string Output;
        }
    }
}
```